# On SharePoint Online, lost the design on Access Requests/pending Req. aspx page

Tags: sharepoint-online

On SharePoint Online, lost the design on Access Requests/pending Req. aspx page. Lost the 'Approve/Decline' buttons and 'request For' field is empty. I can't figure out what is going on. Can you please help? I added Before and after picture of page design. How I change the page again with nice buttons for approve and decline. Thanks?
[image: nt]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a current bug, see advisory message SP207180 that is posted in the Office 365 admin center and suggested workaround:

> Title: All admins may be unable to address access requests for classic
>   SharePoint Online sites in admin center
>
> User Impact: Admins are unable to approve or deny access requests to
>   classic sites in the SharePoint Online admin center.
>
> More info: The approve and deny buttons aren’t populating.
>
> **As a workaround, admins can sort the users requests using any field
>   and the accept/ decline buttons will populate.**
>
> Current status: We've validated a code fix for this issue and expect
>   deployment to complete by Monday, March 30, 2020.
>
> Scope of impact: This issue may affect any admin attempting to approve
>   or deny user access requests to classic SPO sites through the SPO
>   Admin center.
>
> Estimated time to resolve: We expect deployment to be completed on
>   Monday, March 30, 2020.
>
> Root cause: A recent deployment caused the accept/ decline button not
>   to populate for admins within the SPO admin center.